# Can you force a generic type to be generic too?

Tags: java, generics

Suppose you have a generic class

```
class MyClass<T> { ... }
```

You can force `T` to extend or implement a class or an interface, respectively, by writing

```
class MyClass<T extends ThisClassOrThisInterface> { ... }
```

You can even make this construction fully parametric, by abstracting on `ThisClassOrThisInterface`, namely

```
class MyClass<U, T extends U> { ... }
```

**My question is**: Is there a way to force `T` to be a parameterized type? For instance, in a way that

```
class AnotherClass extends MyClass<List<?>>
```

shall be fine, because `List` is a generic type, but

```
class AnotherClass extends MyClass<Object>
```

shall not, because `Object` cannot be parameterized over any type.

---

I was trying to understand how much you can play with generics. In particular, I was trying to implement the following class (pretend that `<T<?>>` forces `T` to be a generic type):

```
class MyClass<T<?>> {

    <A> Function<A, T<A>> myMethod() { ... }

}
```

Comment: As far as I can tell this isn't (currently) possible. But I also can't imagine a situation where you want a rather open generic T (without any boundaries) but still require it to be generic. If you expect something specific and want to support certain behaviour, then you can add boundaries. For example, when you want your `T` to be a collection type: `class MyClass<T extends Collection<?>>`

Comment: @Tom Well, if it were possible, then you would be able to design the `Monad` interface

Comment: Yeah, that definitely isn't possible.  Java doesn't support higher-kinded types.